# Loop Through Files

Tags: vba, excel

In **row B I have a list of codes** and in **H2 I have a folder path** that contains all the files for these listed codes.

I am trying to loop through this list, activate the corresponding file, copy and paste the values into their corresponding tab in the original file. Although I can not seem to get this code to work.

Can someone please tell me how to fix it?

```
Sub Master_Recipe()

Dim MainLoop As Integer
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim WBmain As Workbook
Dim Fac As Integer

MainLoop = 2
Set WBmain = ActiveWorkbook

    Do While MainLoop < 15
        Fac = Range("B" & MainLoop).Value
        Set WB = Range("H2").Value & Fac & " - Recipe Book" 'Object required error here

        Workbooks(WB).Activate
            Range("C:G").Copy

        Workbooks("WBmain").Activate
        Worksheets("Fac").Activate
            Range("C:G").Paste

        MainLoop = MainLoop + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: "set WB = range("H2").value" I get an object required error

Answer (score 4):

There are quite a few issues to address (so I'll be updating the answer as you provide clarification).

`Range` without a defined sheet is VERY bad practice.

```
Sub Master_Recipe()

Dim MainLoop As Integer
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim WBmain As Workbook
Dim Fac As Integer

Set WBmain = Application.Workbooks.Open("WBmain")

    For MainLoop = 2 to 14
        Fac = WBMain.Sheets("NAME OF SHEET with Data").Range("B" & MainLoop).Value
        Set WB = Application.Workbooks.Open(WBMain.Sheets("NAME OF SHEET with Data").Range("H2").Value & Fac & " - Recipe Book")

        WB.Sheets("Name of sheet in workbook").Range("C:G").Copy
        WBMain.Sheets("Fac").Range("C:G").Paste

    Next MainLoop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Chris, I am still getting a "Sub or Function not defined" error on "Set WBmain = Workbook("WBmain")"

Comment: @OriMeir Cleaned up the code to store a workbook correctly in the variable

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the line you said:

```
Set WB = Range("H2").Value & Fac & " - Recipe Book"
```

WB is declared as a workbook, but you are trying to make it equal to a string.

What you want is:

```
Set WB = Application.Workbooks.Open(Range("H2").Value & Fac & " - Recipe Book")
```

assuming that the created string contains the complete path to the file.

If you do this, you will have problems with this line:

```
Workbooks(WB).Activate
```

This is because WB is declared as a workbook, but you are trying to use it as a sttring.  You need to do either:

```
WB.Activate
```

or

```
Workbooks(Wb.Name).Activate
```

I think you intended on declaring WB as a string, in which case the only change you need is:

```
Dim WB As String
```

assuming the file is already open.

****EDIT****

If you do this, you need to get rid of the "Set" keyword, so the line should be:

```
WB = Range("H2").Value & Fac & " - Recipe Book"
```

Comment: Do this but also specify the sheet's range as Chrismas007 pointed out.

Comment: Agreed.  I didn't look at that part of it.  Look at Chrismas007s answer to fix that issue as you could have problems when trying to copy/paste.

Comment: @DavidG  I have made a few edits given your advice. Yet I still get errors on the Set WB line. (Object Required) Can you see why?"

Comment: Oh, If you Dim WB as String, you need to remove the "Set" word from the line.

Comment: I think the range you are reffering to (or that VB thinks you're referring to) doesn't exist. I'd really specify WB.Sheet1.Range("H2"). maybe that's it?

Answer (score 1):

You are **trying to set a string as a workbook object**, that is why you have the error :

I added a temp variable to show you where the problem come from :

```
Sub Master_Recipe()

Dim MainLoop As Integer, _
    WB As Workbook, _
    WBmain As Workbook, _
    Fac As Integer, _
    TpStrWb As String

MainLoop = 2
Set WBmain = ActiveWorkbook

    Do While MainLoop < 15
        Fac = WBmain.Sheets("Fac").Range("B" & MainLoop).Value
        '---------Changes here-------------
        TpStrWb = WBmain.Sheets("Fac").Range("H2").Value & Fac & " - Recipe Book"
        Set WB = Workbooks.Open(TpStrWb)
        '---------Changes here-------------

        WB.Range("C:G").Copy

        WBmain.Sheets("Fac").Range("C1").Paste

        MainLoop = MainLoop + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```